# SOMME.SI (SUMIF in English)

Tags: excel

I am new to excel, and i have just an issue and need fast to be resovled, thanks in advance:
what's the function's meaning in excel, can you please explain me a little, thanks:

```
=SOMME.SI('SUIVI STABILITE'!D$4:AL$4;Feuil2!$A$3;'SUIVI STABILITE'!D24:AL24)
```

ps:SUIVI STABILITE,Feuil2 are different windows in the same excel file, just the function i need fast to resolve.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BVgsVOGgNs7N8gfi9YCQAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=somme.si+excel

Comment: Please use meaningful titles for your questions. "I have an excel issue" has absolutely no meaning, and neither does "I am new to excel" - neither of those will have value to a future reader who finds them in a search result. Your title should describe *a specific issue* that you're having; the tag explains that it's in *excel*. (And if you need "fast to be resolved", pay someone to resolve it for you. This is not your personal assistance site. Your question is no more important or urgent than any other question here.)

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/fr-ca/excel-help/somme-si-HP005209292.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function takes the Value in Sheet "Feuil2", Cell A3 and compares that to the values in sheet "SUIVI STABILITE", cells from D4 to AL4.  It then adds all of the values in sheet "SUIVI STABILITE", cells from D24 to AL24 that are in the same columns as the matches from the first 2 conditions.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.